# Make classes in javascript with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I want to make a Rain drop efect on Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        function Drop(x,y,larg,alt){
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            this.larg=larg;
            this.alt=alt;
        }
        var a = new Drop(canvas.width/4,0,2,25);

        function draw(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.fillStyle="blue";

            ctx.fillRect(a.x,a.y,a.larg,a.alt)
            a.y++;
        }
        setInterval(draw, 5);
```

With this code i can make just one drop, by this i think in make this "var a" a array.
How can i declare this array in code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function Drop(x,y,larg,alt){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.larg=larg;
    this.alt=alt;
}
var a = [];
a = push(new Drop(canvas.width/4,0,2,25));

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";

    ctx.fillRect(a.x,a.y,a.larg,a.alt)
    a.y++;
}
setInterval(draw, 5);
```

or with es6 classes:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


class Drop {
  constructor (x,y,larg,alt) => {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.larg=larg;
    this.alt=alt;
   }
}
var a = [new Drop(canvas.width/4,0,2,25)];

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";

    ctx.fillRect(a.x,a.y,a.larg,a.alt)
    a.y++;
}
setInterval(draw, 5);
```